# Extracting data from xml using python in oracle soa suite 12c

Tags: python, xml, soa, oracle12c, jdeveloper

I am new to Oracle soa suite 12c(jdeveloper). I want to know that is it possible to extract the data from xml file and store the final result in csv file using python script in Oracle soa suite 12c jdeveloper? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

why would you need to do that, oracle SOA Suite provides native functionality that does that in the file Adapter.

see here for an example in 11g:
http://orasoatech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/generating.html

If you need any further help then contact me through my blog, http://jtyreman.blogspot.com

Comment: Thanks for the information @jityreman. Sure, I will contact you if I face any further problem.